# ECharts heatmap - Show ellipsis if the label is long

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, echarts

I am using heatmap from echarts. My requirement is, if the label is long I want to show ellipsis so that the label does not overflow to another cell. Please find the link to the [Playground](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmurCMAM4SQyEBEmItxAvgDTECG0EAth9dEIAzDtnIBTdugDmAJwgATQqhKwAFuIjS1YOgFYADAFJaUkgzoBGY03RtiADwCCDiOWXF0YAJ4hxdAGN-cWlgWW9TT1gFfg5CAG1aSwAmDlNYJLTWDNT02gBmLIyAFiLaPTKANjKAdjKADjKATjLrVstW5MZspO6cvoKB4oG9AcqBmoH6gaaB6znLRgBdM3RyEGwqJ1lxOKJVNbVgAHdCMFkAV3Eo5hYzbxc3D1UfP0Dg0PDI1RiwPcSAMr8C6yGIRHoAMXkYLyABU1CDyDCegB1cQKaDiJEccEZWFXbG42gAWRgyIyAIu0BhKyi602YG2u2eB3IR1OGEu11UtzsZgAbm4LqJiRwCPsSDwIIJYAZVrA-A5CNZ5UFsAELtgOAAjbD-TlXeVhCDiaC6DJHeQALxgf2w3xIeqE5toAVNYHEsgd6G1wDAmB4Vj0JjuxAk8ixCRUJGgHB4-toAAUqQE1LAAMIcUHejC-BMafh8bpRLXa8TYFkHEhsk5nLnyqtkSgCQgAcmllAU4lbDYOQjCfH9nuEKYEsAAFEhorEAJLU8QOWDMACUEqrqh2YBBcHiraQHAAPgCfHqMmlYG5YGKNiaFBhgBg1JfyNwQH4wMxW0sAHQAK2A0rjq2AA60CtsuADcURVvY64kPIqaVnBV5IchsCbJiAASmjaOayRytByHHIoYBqIQ-G9nBwD8p6QjYLWsCtk-ChdmBlHrh6DhgAA8jRsh0QxrblpsICUOQPaETB7F8pJS7yr8_yEfEcqytkei0lW8SWNkKmWBpBzxMkOk9AAtLQ-mqPE-TGRkZkWSQ8TFDZtB2b28R6M5rlKZUnnmW5NS-fZ6DxPUgVuU0YVKSqqm2X5UXaTFyRBbAWlGTFxTJVp1kxXpbmWE5OWZZYHkxfkRU-elRUBTFlRFaFlV5RFDVKRRpWZckCUqWVbnJGlKlJT12Uqepbm6dkNRFdkCUuXFmlpdNXmadlC2zQZBUrZlJUbW5FXbUp1V7Zp9WHQZTUnZZ0UJSN8VTdkA1RfNd1Fct2S1Xl63ZE0RVbVNuVRbtr1VbdsATXlx3ZPURVnVN91zWNsDXXNCVXe1j0g-1L2wLDBn9VNk1Y3jPV3aZq2WdlaUzZlBUU4tBklTTpMORVDOZdVLNufV7NKU1XOadFaXdTdBNY0VaXzc9xOwF972S5DeX01NBjlZLb1RWzal1ZLiMGZYPMaz1uPoz1CVpRlPVi09g2S2bSldeN-PZYLc3ZNllNuY7JNUy7ntuSVru05ZFX-4zwXVcHmX1ctmVNeHeV2wjRUJdlNt8wL9t5R7sD5UVBXLU7Ot-zDyuwNl0tq97CdgxX2sXTHivtfHqtIxXKcGb1LcYxXf2aSp6347n7XZAVbtKcnPtKQVw8Bw5JV9ztQ_j5p1VTyHKX1Sv0cLyLcdb63F0JZPotb9jF1j7Ae8Oflu_fVv2d5RV60n5fy-E1F68Q1DW81w5rUD8bW-gxaqbF2ndz6LxxmpS2UVIFZ0HgjcBZMYH50sgVEqI9NIlTQdPYKFUsGr3iNVPBEcYFP2Ck1IhO94Hn0TjA7uOs0qYIllQ6wOcYHf2CsVGBgC-a4N-kDKhTcdb1QoVFch-sWrDRAf_KhF9grtyoaQlKyRsoiJ7q9V-fN1GxTgRVdBBlsq6OwSlAqhj8ElVMZlCqFj_JaL0ZZeq1jua2KMVpFSu0aGwEcanLRiispaLoRdExUiormKHsXLxOtqoRIug4hBl8mrRJ_m4jRbcErM1Rj40BVilhRByXYHJzAgA&_source=echarts-doc-preview).